# Disabling NetworkManager, lost connectivity

Tags: networking, centos7, networkmanager

I am trying to figure out why my CentOS 7 server is not able to connect to the internet after disabling NetworkManager (installation requirement by cPanel). I have followed this [tutorial here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/3/html/Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/Disabling_Network_Manager.html) on how to disable NetworkManager. I have done it and when I go ahead and do a reboot on my CentOS 7 server, I'm unable to ping or SSH the server. I went to KVM the server and from the server side, I am unable to do pings. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: Is the CentOS 7 running off a Kernel-based Virtual Machine or bare-metal server? Can you check if you can do ping 4.2.2.2 and traceroute 4.2.2.2 and confirm if you are able to see any traffic.

Comment: I am getting "connect: Network is unreachable"

Comment: I am running this CentOS on a VMware ESXi virtual machine.

Comment: Because when you use network manager the normal configuration scripts are left empty?  I'm not a RH/CentOS guy (stopped RH in '99) but in Debian/Mint/Ubuntu the `/etc/network/interfaces` file for a NetworkManager managed system typically has a minimal reference to the network card, specifying "don't do anything automatically".  This lets NWM take over and manage it.  So... go back and configure your network as you normally would on a non-NetworkManager box...